# Expanding a UITextView

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, uitextview

I have a problem with corner buttons in a text view.

When I click the corner buttons the textview should be expanded depends on the particular button. Let us take a left lower corner button, it should be expanded in lower left side.

Similarly it should be working for other three corners.

Comment: Please update your title so it doesn't only contain your username.

Comment: @notreallyJake You too can edit posts (or at least suggest edits)!

Comment: @jtbandes I'm aware of that, but with a description like that (the question is really badly formulated), I'm not creative enough to think of a matching title.

Comment: Please explain what the problem is and what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to set a new frame on the UITextView?! What is the problem?

Example for lower extension:

```
UITextView* yourTextView;
CGRect currentFrame = yourTextView.frame;
currentFrame.size.height += 50;  // extension to the bottom with 50 points
yourTextView.frame = currentFrame;
```

If you want to extend towards the top, also adjust the y position:
`currentFrame.origin.y -= 50;  // move 50 points towards the top`